# Constructing an unrestricted grammar for a^n b^m c^n d^m

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

I've been trying to construct an unrestricted grammar which has the language:

`L = {a^n b^m c^n d^m | n>0, m>0}`

But I can't seem to figure it out without making the derivations run an unreasonably long amount of time.  Can anyone help me devise an elegant way to create this grammar?

Edit: In order to clarify, I was trying to find an Unrestricted Grammar that would run in `O(n^2)` time or better.  As it stood, all of my solutions were exponential, which made parsing very long strings prohibitively costly.

Comment: What grammar have you been thinking of?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We want to help you with your specific problems, not just do your (home-)work. However, as it is we don't know what this problem is and thus how to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the following:
$$
\begin{align*}
&S \to XY \\
&X \to aXC | aC \\
&Y \to BYd | Bd \\
&CB \to BC \\
&aB \to ab \\
&bB \to bb \\
&Cd \to cd \\
&Cc \to cc \\
\end{align*}
$$
In this grammar you need to apply $O(nm)$ rules to get $a^nb^mc^nd^m$.

Comment: You're a lifesaver!  This is so much faster than anything I've looked at.

Comment: Why should this be correct? Also, please consider not to encourage [undesirable posting behaviour](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594).